# Not able to get image src using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using below regex to append a element in front of image tag, but it's not working. I took this code from [Add link around img tags with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985250/add-link-around-img-tags-with-regexp)

```
preg_replace('#(<img[^>]+ src="([^"]*)" alt="[^"]*" />)#', '<a href="$2" ...>$1</a>', $str)
```

However, If I use below code without src, it works.

```
 preg_replace('#(<img[^>]+ alt="[^"]*" />)#', '<a href="" ...>$1</a>', $str)
```

Any reason why I am not able to get the src from the image tag.

My image tag is `<img src="" alt="">`

Comment: Trying to use regexs to process HTML is bound to be illegible at best, and as shown just is to strict in others.  Try using DOMDocument to process it and you should get better results. (try `#(<img[^>]+src="([^"]*)" alt="[^"]*">)#` for your pattern, but this is still fragile)

Comment: @NigelRen I have tried your pattern. It's still not working.

Comment: That's why I'm saying - don't use it!, do it properly - what happens if someone codes their anchor tags `<img alt="" src="" />`?

Comment: Just escape the last forward slash `/`, in the pattern which has `src`. [And it will work](https://regexr.com/42pro)

Comment: @rv7 I have solved this issue, using this pattern `#(<img.*?src="(.*?)"[^\>]+>)#`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do something like this is to use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class as it is independent of how people write their HTML (e.g. putting the alt attribute before the src attribute). Something like this would work for your case:

```
$html = '<div id="x"><img src="/images/xyz" alt="xyz" /><p>hello world!</p></div>';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$images = $xpath->query('//img');
foreach ($images as $img) {
    // create a new anchor element
    $a = $doc->createElement('a');
    // copy the img src attribute to the a href attribute
    $a->setAttribute('href', $img->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue);
    // add the a to the images parent
    $img->parentNode->replaceChild($a, $img);
    // make the image a child of the <a> element
    $a->appendChild($img);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div id="x"><a href="/images/xyz"><img src="/images/xyz" alt="xyz"></a><p>hello world!</p></div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nd4Gm)